# Determine median element of a nested array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, yield, median

I would need a median calculating method in Ruby, which works with nested arrays too, similarly as "uniq" and "sort_by": with those I can define by the block, which of the nested array values should be taken into consideration.

```
class Array
   def median
      . . .
   end
end

puts [[1,3],[2,5],[3,-4]].median{|z,w| z}

=> [2,5]

puts [[1,3],[2,5],[3,-4]].median{|z,w| w}

=> [1,3]
```

I am sure I should deal with "yield" somehow but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: How are you computing the median for a nested array?

Comment: Step 1: define what "the median of a nested array" is even supposed to mean. Step 2: write down the code to compute what you have just defined. Step 3: if you have trouble with Step 2, ask a question on [so]. Since there is no such thing as "the median of a nested array", we unfortunately cannot help you unless you complete Step 1 and tell us what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the median needs things sorted, you could just delegate out to [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and work on the results of that:

```
class Array
  def median(&block)
    block = :itself unless block_given?

    sorted = sort_by(&block)
    if length.odd?
      sorted[sorted.length / 2]
    else
      sorted[sorted.length / 2 - 1, 2]
    end
  end
end
```

Sample runs:

```
[13, 23, 11, 16, 15, 10, 26].median # => 15
# hyperbole showing the block is used on single elements
count = 0; [13, 23, 11, 16, 15, 10, 26].median { |a| count += 1 } # => 16
# even length data set
# usually you'd average these, but that becomes trickier with nested arrays
[14, 13, 23, 11, 16, 15, 10, 26].median # =>  [14, 15]

# your examples:
[[1,3], [2,5], [3,-4]].median { |z,_| z} # => [2, 5]
[[1,3], [2,5], [3,-4]].median { |_,w| w } # => [1, 3]

# added [6, -6] to your examples:
[[1,3], [2,5], [3,-4], [6, -6]].median { |z,_| z } # => [[2, 5], [3, -4]]
[[1,3], [2,5], [3,-4], [6, -6]].median { |_,w| w } # => [[3, -4], [1, 3]]
```

You don't specify what should happen for even-length arrays. For a math median (If I remember my maths correctly) you would average the two center-most elements, but then comes the question of what the average of 2 different arrays looks like. This takes the simple (for us) approach of returning both the center elements and the caller has to decide how to handle them. (What if it's not another array nested inside, what if it's a list of people and you want the median by last name, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the median of an array is defined as follows. For an array `a` containing an odd number of elements, the median  is `[m]` where `m` is an element of `a` for which `e <=> m` is non-positive for `a.size/2` other elements `e` and `e <=> m` is non-negative for the remaining `a.size/2` other elements `e`. For arrays having an even number of elements, the median is `[m, n]`, where `m` and `n` are elements of `a` for which `m <=> n` is non-positive, `e <=> m` is non-positive for `a.size/2-1` other elements `e`and `e <=> n` is non-negative for the remaining `a.size/2-1` other elements `e`.

```
class Array
  def median
    min_by(1+self.size/2, &:itself).pop(self.size.odd? ? 1 : 2)
  end
end

[2, 4, 5, 3, 1].median
  #=> [3]
[2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1].median
  #=> [3, 4]
[3, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1].median
  #=> [3, 4]
['hamster', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat'].median
  #=> ["dog", "fish"]
[[1, 3], [2, 5], [3, -4]].median
  #=> [[2, 5]]
[[2,6], [3,-4], [1,3], [2,5]].median
  # => [[2, 5], [2, 6]]
arr = [[[3,1], 1], [[4], 2], [[2,1], 4, 1], [[3,1], 0], [[1,2,3], 5]]
arr.median
  #=> [[[3, 1], 0]]
```

In the last example

```
arr.sort
  #=> [[[1, 2, 3], 5], [[2, 1], 4, 1], [[3, 1], 0], [[3, 1], 1], [[4], 2]]
```

See [Enumerable#min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by). The optional argument was introduced in Ruby v2.1.

Answer (score -1):

flatten() is your friend here. It collapses a nested array (or any enumerable) into a single array. Then, it becomes trivial to compute the median:

```
class Array
  def median
    array = self.flatten.sort
    if array.size % 2 == 1
      array[array.size / 2]
    else
      mid = array.size / 2
      (array[mid] + array[mid-1]) / 2.0
    end
  end

  def mean
    self.flatten.reduce(:+) / self.flatten.size.to_f  
  end
end
```

This lets you do:

```
irb> a
=> [[1, 3], [2, 5], [3, -4]]
irb> a.median
=> 2.5
irb> c
=> [[1, 2, 3, 6], [4, 5, [100]]]
irb> c.median
=> 4
irb> c.mean
=> 17.285714285714285
```

For performance, you may want to compute self.flatten once, then do both arithmetic operations off of that array. But, unless you're using huge data, it probably won't matter, and hopeful Ruby will optimize that for you. But honestly, I wouldn't worry about the performance.

[Edited, after @kiddorails pointed out I had confused median and mean! Thanks, Kiddo!]

Comment: Because we have more important work to do. Because this is a pretty light-weight operation. Because any modern language should catch such an easy optimization and do it for us. Because when performance does show that it is a problem, a profiler will show us where it's worth investing our energy, and it almost certainly won't be in an array copy. 

But I am glad you asked! :)

Comment: And that's not median, that's the average.

Comment: Ack! How right you are, @kiddorails! Let me take another stab at that.

Comment: I don't quite agree with that approach of programming. It takes very little time to code in this way and make a system full of time-bombs, which can tick any second. I second with premature optimization being root of evil; but I think optimization like above is pretty basic and should be there by default.

Comment: That way quickly spirals out of control when working in teams - N+1 queries is classical example in Rails for that, where I have seen developers leaving basic optimization for very end and it often bring down the whole system(s).

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to include the `mean` method in your answer.